# Fixing non-displayed headerlinks

Tags: internet-explorer, layout, web-parts

I have the following page I'm working on:

http://69.134.44.19:8000/products.html?v=products

In Google Chrome and Firefox, it displays correctly, in IE, however, all the links are pushed down under the logo.  It also (I now realize) isn't using my :hover thing in my css for all of my product elements on the pages.  It also isn't aligning things correctly on this page:

http://69.134.44.19:8000/cprod.html?cat=Doughnuts&subp=Zebra%20Doughnut&cst=2&hash=95f9aa9f327881e9ce3eae56af43da3c

Any ideas of how I can fix this?  Why is IE such an outlier?  Why can't it just follow rules?

Are there any tools online to make my site cross browser safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, the answer was quite simple.  After some google searches, I came across this:

http://friendlybit.com/css/cross-browser-strategies-for-css/

At the top of all of my pages, I have a comment containing contact information and copyright info.  Apparently, when IE goes to read the page, it doesn't find the Doctype because it isn't in the right location so IE initiates [Quirk Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).  Moving the Doctype deceleration to the top of all the pages (above my comment) fixed the problem completely!